# Access thread from eventhandler

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I am trying to access a thread in main from an eventhandler but I cannot get this to work. Here is my code:

```
 public class Navigation
    {
        private bool _stop = false;            

        // This method that will be called when the thread is started
        public void Left()
        {
            while (!_stop)
            {
              ...
            }
        }
       public void RequestStop()
       {
          _stop = true;
        }
    };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Navigation navigation = new Navigation();
   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(navigation.Left));
}

 static void event_handler(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
 {
    thread.Start();
 }
```

The thread.Start() command is what I want to achive. What can I do to obtain this?

EDIT:

The solution was pretty simple (See comments). However I need a little additional help. I would like to be able to start and stop this thread again and again. I have tried the following:

```
if (condition == true)
        {
            thread.Start();
        }

        if (condition == false)
        {
            navigation.RequestStop();
        }
```

This works the first time. The thread starts and I am able to stop it again. However the second time I try to start the thread I get a ThreadStateExecption. What am I missing?

Comment: declare `thread` as a static member of the class (not in the method)...

Comment: Thank you. I think it is too late for programming ;)

Comment: Depends on your time zone :)

Answer (score 0):

Your thread left scope after main. Declare it outside of main.